# How to only animate newly dropped Annotations?

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I have an app that allows users to select colleges on one view and after they have selected, that view dismisses and a map appears. Currently, I am using the code below but it animates all annotations. I would like existing annotations to not animate and only animate the newly selected college when the view dismisses.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseID = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true
        pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
        pinView?.animatesDrop = true
    } else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
        pinView?.animatesDrop = true
    }
    return pinView
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom annotation and add a boolean value to it to check if it has been added before or not.

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var name: String!
    var exists: Bool!
}
```

And then use `CustomPointAnnotation` when you add the annotations and check if `exists` is `true` then you don´t animate if `false` then animate.